# Getopt. -help argument doesn't work.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
    while getopts ":help :a" opt; do
      case $opt in
        help)
        echo "-p to print";
          ;;

....
```

I run it like this.

```
myscript -help
```

Help doesn't get called, I do not know why...

If I change help with just h and start the script like this everything works just fine.

```
myscript -h
```

What is my problem?

Comment: -l is needed to support long options. Note that "getopts" varies between systems, which "getopts" is a bash builtin and will work everywhere. "getopts" does not support long options.

Comment: please put this as an answer so I can close this thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is non-standard syntax. The option `-help` would be just a shortcut for `-h -e -l -p`. Note that most commands have one-character options with dash (`-h`) and long names with double dash (`--help`).